# What does an apostrophe at the end of a derivation path mean?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, hardened-derivation

If I generate addresses with `m/44'/0'/0'/0', m/44'/0'/0'/1'`, what is the difference compared with `m/44'/0'/0'/0, m/44'/0'/0'/1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates that hardened derivation should be used for that step.

BIP 32 [specifies](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#extended-keys) a "hardened" derivation method. This method is different from the "unhardened" method in that it requires the parent private key in order to derive the child private key.

For example, the path index `44'` indicates that the 44th hardened key should be derived.

Comment: thx,  but, parent 'BIP32 Extended Private Key' or 'BIP32 Root Key'?

Comment: There is no special distinction between parent and root.